# PHP cURL keep connections alive for subsequent requests (not session, not cookie)

Tags: php, keep-alive, php-curl

we need to send data from PHP to an external worker. The data is transmitted through a HTTP interface.

Unfortunately we hit a limitation. It looks like PHP is using a new connection for every single PHP execution which causes issues thanks to too many unused keep-alive/"TIME_WAIT" connections.

Is there any way to use those connections with subsequent PHP executions instead of creating new ones?

Please note, this is not about keeping sessions alive, this is about keeping the amount of connections small by reusing them.

```
netstat -tan | awk '$5 ~ /:8139/ {print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 ESTABLISHED
  28230 TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: you want to run a php command with curl that takes long time?

Comment: It looks like the following enhancement request,    https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71832. One the guys was trying a workaround at server level.